# Swig typemap. Return Python enum object from C wrapper

Tags: python, c++, enums

As I found out swig cannot convert C++ enums to Python enums object, so I created py file with enum declarations.
For example I have enum in C++:

```
enum class Color
{
  red, green, blue
};
```

and in py file:

```
from enum import Enum
class Color(Enum):
    red = 0
    green = 1
    blue = 2
```

for in typemap i use something like this:

```
*$1 = (int) PyLong_AsLong(PyObject_GetAttr($input, PyString_FromString("value")));
```

And it works fine (because int is valid type for C enum value). But for out typemap I have to create Python enum object and return it. I have no ideas what is the right way to do this.